# Failed to start couchbase-server.service: Unit couchbase-server.service is masked

Tags: linux, service, couchbase

couchbase service stopped , so i started it manually by exec following command:

`sudo service couchbase-server start` and got response

```
Failed to start couchbase-server.service: Unit couchbase-server.service is masked.
```

I have ubuntu 16.04LTS and couchbase 5.1

Answer (score 2):

you can unmask your service

```
sudo systemctl unmask couchbase-server
sudo systemctl start couchbase-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to `$CouchbaseHome` and run following command to start and stop manually

Start

```
 ./bin/couchbase-server \-- -noinput -detached
```

Shutdown

```
./bin/couchbase-server -k
```

Comment: I just wasn't sure about this backslash. It was not visible outside the edition so I deleted it. And yet it was needed. Right.

Comment: Yes backslach is needed.